# Expo Image editor from ImagePicker API

Tags: react-native, expo, exponentjs

Exponents ImagePicker API lets you pick an image from your library. After picking an image it opens the image in an image editor that lets you edit the image. Is there any way to skip the image picking part and directly go to the editor screen?
Like I give in an image URI and it opens that image in the image editor screen of expo.

Answer (score 0):

Set `allowsEditing={false}`. See [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker#allowsediting-boolean----whether-to-show-a) for details.

> allowsEditing (boolean) -- Whether to show a UI to edit the
>   image/video after it is picked. Images: On Android the user can crop
>   and rotate the image and on iOS simply crop it. Videos: On iOS user
>   can trim the video. Defaults to false.

Comment: Anjal, I want the image editor part alone. Not the image picking part alone. Setting 'alllowsEditing' to false would just give me the image picking part.